# Python pyqt5 how to convert QMainWindow to QGraphicsView and preview it with QPainter

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qpainter, qprinter

I'm trying to use `QtPainter` to preview my entire `QMainWindow` (all the contents) so that I can print it from the preview menu. All my attempts have failed. Below is sample code.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import uic, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport, QtGui
import sys, os
class mainwindowUI(QMainWindow):
    resized = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(mainwindowUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.text = QLineEdit('Hello World', self)
        self.print_()
        self.show()
    def print_(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog() # PyQt5
        # dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        # Start painter
        painter.begin(printer)
        # Grab a widget you want to print
        screen = self.grab()
        # Draw grabbed pixmap
        painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
        # End painting
        painter.end()
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView(painter)
        self.graphicsView.render(QPainter(printer))
        self.viewer.render(QPainter(printer))

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            self.editor.document().print_(dialog.printer())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainwindowUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I want it, the `QtPainter` preview window showing my `QMainWindow` and everything inside of it. It appears `QtPainter` takes in a `QGraphicsView` so somehow my mainwindow has to get converted to that....(I am using a `.ui` file in my final project that I designed in QtCreator just in case that makes some things more difficult)